# possible match vlookup excel formula?

Tags: excel, formulas

Good Morning,
I am trying to write a formula that will let me compare column b in workbook A with column b in workbook b and well as column f in workbook A and column H in work book B and if they all match return the answer of what is listed in column N workbook B.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: this is most likely a duplicate of about 3 million questions, and also you do not show the formula you are currently using

Comment: You shold be showing us with an example of the data

Comment: thank you ok sorry. this is my first time asking a question  I will add an example of the data in the following comment

Comment: Header | Header | Header
:----- | -----: | :----:
Left   | Right  | CenterCreate Date  Unit
5/25/17 1:29  34
5/25/17 1:34  34
5/26/17 23:39  34
5/25/17 0:10  34
5/25/17 3:16  34
5/26/17 22:10  34

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many rows then you can use the and function and drag down for the number of rows you need. This example is set up assuming you have 10 rows in sheets 1 and 2.

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$10=Sheet2!$B$1:$B$10,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$10=Sheet1!$F$1:$F$10,Sheet1!$F$1:$F$10=Sheet2!$H$1:$H$10),Sheet2!N1,"")
```